# Convert Excel to PDF - Java using iText

Tags: java, excel, pdf, itext

I have created an excel file with Apache POI. 
And now I need convert it to PDF. 
I want to use iText, but I want copy the merged cell, styles, etc from excel file to pdf.

How can I achieve this? Because the code sample I've found on the web: [PDF to Excel using iText and Apache POI](http://thinktibits.blogspot.sk/2012/12/POI-iText-Convert-XLS-to-PDF-Java-Program.html) is good but doesn't copy the merged cells, styles.

Any ideas? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use iText, it's best to use iText7. This is the latest version of iText, and substantial bugfixing has been done (especially for tables).

That having been said, when I look at the example, it seems like the example just iterates over all the cells and adds them to an iText Table object.

The exact same thing can be done with iText7. You create a table with the proper amount of columns, and then add cells to it.

Your question (as far as I'm concerned) comes down to "how can I style iText table cells".

This is a piece of sample code that just generates a table. I have indicated where you can style the content of the table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

public static void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Table table = new Table(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("hi");
        // now you can use methods like:
        // para.setFont()
        // para.setFontColor()
        // para.setFontSize()
        table.addCell(para);
    }
    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
}
```

Check out more examples at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-tables

Comment: To add onto Joris' answer: one does not simply "copy styles" from Excel. *You* set the style yourself, and *you* decide what and how. You need Apache POI to read the Excel styles, then do the work yourself to translate that into corresponding iText `setFont`/`setFontColor`/`setFontSize` statements.

Comment: @Joris and how I can merge cells ? http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/colspan-and-rowspan -> example from here isn't good ...

Comment: Can you explain why the example isn't good? Also, are you talking about merging cells in the input, or in the output?