# File or directory is not created in Android 10 and above device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a multifile converter app , in which user can select a excel file which can be converted into pdf ,  below method is used  to create pdf file that is  working fine in my phone  which is android pie (android 9 ) , but when I run the app in android 10  real device also in emulator no directory is being created . please help me with the code
and requesting runtime permission with dexter library

I added the  line in manifest :-

```
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Permissions :--

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

My CreatePDF method:-

```
 void Convert_to_PDF(Uri path) throws IOException, DocumentException, URISyntaxException {

   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MultiFileCon");



    if (!f.exists()) if ( !f.mkdir()) return;




    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    // System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    Log.d("DATE", formatter.format(date) + ".pdf");

    File pdffilex = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), formatter.format(date) + ".pdf");


    Log.d("ABC", "Convert_to_PDF: "+uriforExcel.getPath());


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "android version is "+android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("VERSION NAME", "Convert_to_PDF: "+android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        File file = new File(path.getPath());//create path from uri
        final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");//split the path.
       filePath = split[1];
        input_document = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    }
    else {
        input_document = new FileInputStream(new File(PathUtil.getPath(this,path)));
    }




    // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);




    // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    // To iterate over the rows
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
    //We will create output PDF document objects at this point
    Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, new FileOutputStream(pdffilex));
    iText_xls_2_pdf.open();
    //we have two columns in the Excel sheet, so we create a PDF table with two columns
    //Note: There are ways to make this dynamic in nature, if you want to.
    PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(7);
    //We will use the object below to dynamically add new data to the table
    PdfPCell table_cell;
    //Loop through rows.
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
            switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                //you need to add more code here based on
                //your requirement / transformations
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                    table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                    Log.d("DOL", cell.getStringCellValue());






                    //feel free to move the code below to suit to your needs
                    my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                    break;
            }
            //next line
        }

        // Log.d("DOL", "Convert_to_PDF: "+datatobe);

    }
    //Finally add the table to PDF document
    iText_xls_2_pdf.add(my_table);
    iText_xls_2_pdf.close();
    //we created our pdf file..
    input_document.close(); //close xls
}
```

Comment: if (!f.exists()) 
       if ( !f.mkdir()) return;

Comment: You are blindly toasting that you created a directory without checking return value of mkdir.

Comment: yes f.mkdir returns false

Comment: Then adapt your code before we continue.

Comment: yes i changed the code  and also replaced HH:mm:ss to HH.mm.ss

Comment: I see no changes yet

Comment: done please check

Comment: If the directory cannot be created you are returning without informing the user. No good user experience. I had left that to you of course.

Comment: i will look into it, but my issue is to create directory so i can store generated pdfs or please provide me any other solution to it

Comment: We wait until you looked into it and saw the results.

Comment: tried in emulator still no directory is being created

Answer (score 0):

> > SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

```
':'
```

is a forbidden character in a file system path.

Try:.

```
 "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method does not work on Android 11 or above version devices for security reasons.

You can easily store your file in a public directory. Here is an example of how you access a public directory in Android Studio.

> Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

so you can try this code in your project.

```java
File baseFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MultiFileCon");

if (!baseFile.exists()) {
    baseFile.mkdirs();
}

File pdfFile = new File(baseFile, "PDF_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".pdf");

Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: pdfFile path is:  " + pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

- here you got path be like: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/MultiFileCon/PDF_1665148985587.pdf`

Comment: MultiFileCon folder is created but no pdf file is generated inside it

Comment: Can you provide exception log.?

Comment: D/MAINERROR: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Book1.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) , but i have added all permission ,

Comment: do you have declare `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest.xml??

Comment: yes i declared it already

Comment: then i think problem in your excel to pdf converter code.   you can check this one => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886648/convert-excel-to-pdf-java-using-itext